# Accessing elements in list in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to access a certain element in a list, and to store that in data.frame. In case the specific object does not have that element, the result should be NA.

Example:

```
list
$A
"mark" "peter" "sam" "il"

$B
"dd" "pp" "tt" "ff" "jj" "rr"

$C
"aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa"
```

Result by calling **the sixth element** in the entire list should be:

result (data. frame):

```
name value

<NA>  A
rr    B
aa    C
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: As others have commented on your previous posts: please provide a easily reproducible example. Also show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply` and `data.frame`:

```
# The list
l <- list(A = c("mark", "peter", "sam", "il"),
          B = c("dd", "pp", "tt", "ff", "jj", "rr"),
          C = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa"))

# extract sixth element in each vector
res <- sapply(l, "[", 6)

# combine to data frame
dat <- data.frame(name = res, value = names(res))

#   name value
# A  <NA>    A
# B    rr    B
# C    aa    C
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I tried using `sapply`, but did not know about the "[" element.

Comment: @Makaroni FWIW, `"["` is a function that you can read as "subset". See  `?"["`.

Comment: @Justin Thanks! I now have one quick sub-question: what if I want to extract the last element of this list, i.e. to have `il` for `A`, `rr` for `B` and `aa` for `C`?

Comment: Write your own function!  `sapply(l, function(x) tail(x, 1))`.

Comment: @Justin Yup, obviously! Thanks!